# How to add script which will show downloaded times in my file sharing site

Tags: php

i'm new to php i created a filesharing site where people upload their files and get a link to share with others which is registration free now i want to show how many times a file is downloaded here is my download.php code.

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * @package     Filehost
 * @author      Ronald Ralinala
 * @copyright   2015 
 * @link        http://filehost
 * @version     1.0.0
 */

include("./utils/config.php");
include("./utils/functions.php");
include("./utils/classes/filesize.php");
require '/utils/config.php';



$access_id = $_GET["id"];

$page_name = "file download";
$css_type = "download";
include("./utils/templates/header.php");
?>


  <div id="content">
<?php
if(!mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `" . $table_prefix . "files` WHERE access_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($access_id) . "'"))) {
?> 
    <img src="/images/instructions.gif" id="instructions" alt="Step 1: Upload your file.  Step 2: Share your private link."/>
    <div id="box">
      <div class="notice">

        <h2>File not found</h2>
        Please verify the URL.
      </div>
    </div>

<?php
}else{
  // fetch file information
  $fileinfo_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `" . $table_prefix . "files` WHERE access_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($access_id) . "'");
  $fileinfo = mysql_fetch_array($fileinfo_result);

  // do expiry calculations
  $current_timestamp = time();
  $expiry_timestamp = $fileinfo["expiry"];

  if( (intval($expiry_timestamp) !== 0) && ($current_timestamp > $expiry_timestamp) ) {



?>
    <img src="/images/instructions.gif" id="instructions" alt="Step 1: Upload your file.  Step 2: Share your private link."/>
    <div id="box">
      <div class="notice">
        <h2>File has expired</h2>
        The file you are trying to download has expired and is no longer available.
      </div>
    </div>
<?php
  }else if( $fileinfo['deleted'] == 1 ) {
?>
  <div id="content">
    <img src="/images/instructions.gif" id="instructions" alt="Step 1: Upload your file.  Step 2: Share your private link."/>
    <div id="box">
      <div class="notice">
        <h2>File Deleted</h2>
        The file you are trying to download has been deleted and is no longer available.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
  }else{
    // Generate a random security string
    $security_id = sha1(time() . uniqid());
    $client_ip = getClientIP();
    $security_expire = time() + (get_config('download_sessionexpiry') * 60);

    // Create download session
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `" . $table_prefix . "dlsession` (`id`, `session_id`, `access_id`, `ip_address`, `expiry`) VALUES (NULL, '" . $security_id . "', '" . $access_id . "', '" . $client_ip . "', " . $security_expire . ");");

    // set file information
    $file_name = $fileinfo["file_name"];
    $file_size = $fileinfo["file_size"];

    // calculate file size
    $file_size_class = new getFileSize();
    $size_text = $file_size_class->fileSizeConversion($file_size, 'B');

    // create file download url
    $file_download_url = "/file/" . $access_id . "/" . $security_id . "/" . rawurlencode($file_name);
?>

    <div id="info">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("Your download will begin immediately");
        setTimeout("window.location = '<?php print $file_download_url; ?>'", <?php print(get_config('download_waittime') * 1000); ?>);
      </script>
      <noscript>
        <a href="<?php print $file_download_url; ?>">Click here to start your download</a>
      </noscript>
    </div>
    <div id="file_info"><strong>
      File Name: <i><?php print shorten_title($file_name); ?></i><br />
      File Size: <?php print $size_text; ?><br /> <br />
      &nbsp; <h1><?php echo file_get_contents('./uploads/counter.txt'); ?> </h1> Page Hits
      <?php echo counter.php;?>




    </div>

    <div id="sponsor">
      <div class="message">Thank you!</div>
      <div style="height: 250px;">
<?php
      // Print out download sponsor code
      print(stripslashes(get_config('download_sponsorcode')));
?>
      </div>
      <img src="/images/ad_box_top_left.gif" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px;" />
      <img src="/images/ad_box_top_right.gif" style="position:absolute; right:0px; top:0px;" />
      <img src="/images/ad_box_bottom_left.gif" style="position:absolute; left:0px; bottom:0px;" />
      <img src="/images/ad_box_bottom_right.gif" style="position:absolute; right:0px; bottom:0px;" />
    </div>
<?php
    }
  }

?>
  </div>
<?php
include("./utils/templates/footer.php");
?>
```

i need a download counter can some one add it for me please?

Comment: are you asking for the time it takes to download or a hit counter?

Comment: No. We are not here to do your job for you. and displaying the download count is the EASIEST part. Nowhere do you show anything on how you count downloads in the first place. **THAT** is the hard part.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a track of downloaded events in a text file; there won't be any db storage necessary.

```
$hit_count = @file_get_contents('hitcount.txt'); 
// read the hit count from file, save this file on the 
// server to get and update hit count

echo $hit_count; 
// display the hit count
// from here. just grab contents from the hitcount.txt 

//when someone downloads the file 
//you want to update the download count
$hit_count++; // increment the hit count by 1

//after the file download successfully, you want to 
//run this code to update the count
@file_put_contents('count.txt', $hit_count); // store the new hit count
```

Comment: unixmiah i tried your code but its not showing anything

Answer (score 0):

First get a list of all access id from database

$access = Select access_id from table where file_id = $file

Then select download session of access id

Foreach access 
Count download session

And you will get an answer